# Emacsclient to get current-buffer?

Tags: emacs, elisp

When I use `emacsclient --eval '(current-buffer)'` it returns `*server*` instead of the `current-buffer` on emacs. I can insert and modify `*server*` with `--eval` command but is there a way to know make it do inserts to the real current buffer? Is there a way to pass a string like `#<buffer index.html>` and have it turn into a buffer object?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try `(window-buffer (selected-window))`.  For example,

```
emacsclient --eval '(with-current-buffer (window-buffer (selected-window)) (insert "foo"))'
```